# special combinatorial sums

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, combinatorics

I know several of combinatorial sums, which is equal to 0. For example,
$$ \sum_{0 \leq j \leq d} (-1)^j {d \choose j}=0$$

$$ \sum_{0 \leq j \leq \frac{d}{2}} (-1)^j {d \choose j}(d-2j)^\alpha=0, \, \text{  as }\alpha \text { is even and } \alpha<d $$

> Let \begin{gather*}
> I(d_1,d_2)=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{d_2-d_1+1}{2}}}{2^{d_1-1} d_1!}\sum_{k=[\frac{d_1}{2}]+1}^{ d_1} { d_1 \choose k}\frac{ (2k-d_1)^{d_2+d_1-1}}{ (d_2{+}d_1{-}2k)!! (d_2{-}d_1{+}2k)!!}\\+
> \frac{1}{2^{d_2-1} d_2!}\sum_{  k=0}^{ \frac{d_2}{2}}{ d_2 \choose k}\dfrac{(-1)^k(d_2-2k)^{d_2+d_1-1}}{  \prod_{i=0}^{d_1} {(d_2-d_1-2k+2i)}}.
>  \end{gather*}
>   Prove that $I(d_1,d_2)=0,$ as $d_2,d_1 \in \mathbb{N},$ $d_2+d_1$ is odd and $d_2>d_1$

I tried. 
$$I(d_1,d_2)=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{d_2-d_1+1}{2}}}{2^{d_1} d_1!}\sum_{k=0}^{ d_1} { d_1 \choose k}\frac{ (2k-d_1)^{d_2+d_1-1}}{ (d_2{+}d_1{-}2k)!! (d_2{-}d_1{+}2k)!!}\\+
\frac{1}{2^{d_2} d_2!}\sum_{  k=0}^{d_2}{ d_2 \choose k}\dfrac{(-1)^k(d_2-2k)^{d_2+d_1-1}}{  \prod_{i=0}^{d_1} {(d_2-d_1-2k+2i)}}.
$$
I used $$ \sum_{0 \leq j \leq d}  {d \choose j}=2^n.$$ 
$$I(d_1,d_2)=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{d_2-d_1+1}{2}}}{2^{d_1+d_2} d_1!}\sum_{k=0}^{ d_1} \sum_{j=0}^{ d_2} { d_2 \choose j} { d_1 \choose k}\frac{ (2k-d_1)^{d_2+d_1-1}}{ (d_2{+}d_1{-}2k)!! (d_2{-}d_1{+}2k)!!}\\+
\frac{1}{2^{d_1+d_2} d_2!}\sum_{  k=0}^{d_2} \sum_{j=0}^{ d_1} { d_1 \choose j} { d_2 \choose k}\dfrac{(-1)^k(d_2-2k)^{d_2+d_1-1}}{  \prod_{i=0}^{d_1} {(d_2-d_1-2k+2i)}}\\
=\frac{1}{2^{d_1+d_2} d_1!d_2!}\sum_{k=0}^{ d_1} \sum_{j=0}^{ d_2} { d_2 \choose j} { d_1 \choose k}(\frac{ (-1)^{\frac{d_2-d_1+1}{2}}(2k-d_1)^{d_2+d_1-1}d_2!}{ (d_2{+}d_1{-}2k)!! (d_2{-}d_1{+}2k)!!}\\+
 \dfrac{(-1)^j d_1!(d_2-2j)^{d_2+d_1-1}}{  \prod_{i=0}^{d_1} {(d_2-d_1-2j+2i)}}).$$
I am stuck with it. What does combinatorial sum help me?
Thanks

Comment: Please explain what $n!!$ means.

Comment: @vonbrand  $$(2k+1)!!=\prod_{i=0} ^k {(2i+1)} =1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2k+1)$$
$$(2k)!!=\prod_{i=1} ^k {(2i)} =2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2k)=2^k \cdot k!$$